# Send ordered keys to correct reducer

Tags: hadoop

If I have keys 0 to 19, and I want to create a partitioner that will send records with keys 0 and 1 to the first reducer, 2 and 3 to the second reducer and so on. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: It is possible. But let us know how many reducers you require and how many keys do you have. The question is too generic to answer at first shot.Is it that you have just 20 keys in total and that you want to pair 2 adjacent keys?

Comment: So it will be with 10 reducers, however the number of keys was a random number. It could actually be any possible number, what's important is conserving the order of the keys with the reducer, in other words reducer 1 could do keys 4,5,6,7 and reducer 2 could do key 8. The only important thing is that the order is conserved.

Comment: @KOM the order is always conserved, but do you need consecutive following keys, so 4,5,6,7 or is 4,6,8 enough? If you don't know how many keys you have, it is impossible with a single MapReduce job.

Answer (score 1):

In all cases, **you need to know the number of reducers before hand**. The solution is also quite generic as per the level of understanding from your question,

Looking at your question, the following sequence occurs,

```
Reducer0 keys 0,1|Reducer1 keys 2,3|Reducer2 keys 4,5|Reducer3 keys 6,7|
Reducer4 keys 8,9|Reducer5 keys 10,11|Reducer6 keys 12,13|Reducer7 keys 14,15|
Reducer8 keys 16,17|Reducer9 keys 18,19
```

In this case, get the integer value of the key in the partitioner

set the reducer to key/2

if Key is 13, reducer will be 13/2 = 6
 if key is 14, reducer will be 14/2 = 7

```
 public static class CustomPartitioner extends Partitioner<IntWritable, Whatever> {

        @Override
        public int getPartition(IntWritable key, Whatever value, int numReduceTasks) {

           int keyAsInteger = key.get();
       return keyAsInteger/2;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I did not mention that this is how the Hash Partitioner works. It means that you need to do the things by hand and is not a hadoop out of the box functionality. What I meant by my example is that the Partitioner has to be written that way. Also added a code fragment. I don't think that was required to be coded and my initial answer itself gave the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text, Text> {
static int[] number = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9, 10, 10};
    @Override
    public int getPartition(IntWritable key, Text value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return number[key];
    } 
}
```